# How to connect a nest thermostat with the heat link

Tags: nest-thermostat

I'm considering buying a Nest learning thermostat. As I live in the Eu, I understand this comes with the heat link.
My question is: how one is supposed to connect the nest with the heat link, by wire or wifi? Could it be either?

Answer (score 1):

After some more research, I have found this [link](https://support.google.com/googlenest/answer/9256506?hl=en-GB#zippy=%2Chow-are-nest-thermostats-made-for-europe-and-north-america-different), where it seems the installation of the Nest piece can be wireless.

Comment: Link only answers tend to get deleted. Please edit your answer and provide a summary. Note, you are allowed to tick ot.